# How to make the Windows guest machine use more the one CPU?

Tags: fedora, windows, cpu, kvm

I do believe this question has been posted before not only here but on Linux forums as well.
However I could not implement the solutions, I am probably missing something obvious.

KVM
Host: Fedora 23
1. Guest: Windows 10 UEFI
2. Guest: Windows 10 UEFI

Host machine has 3 GPU's plugged in and I have managed to pass two to the VM's, and that part works just fine. Although I did not manage to pass AMD cards to the VM's as the driver kept crashing the VM, the two nvidia cards I have now seam to work just fine without problems.

Now the problem is that on a Windows 10 VM, no matter what I do I can not get it to use more then one CPU core.

Tried configuring it via virt manager, tried editing the XML file, but no matter what, the VM uses only one core even though I can see more then one CPU in the Device manager on the VM.

Comment: This is a Q&A site, not a forum. It would be appropriate to investigate the significant differences by reading the help pages when you post here.

Comment: If you can see more than one CPU in the Device Manager on Windows, then KVM is configured correctly and the problem is with Windows itself; which is off-topic on this site.

Comment: I am sorry Anthon if I have made a mistake in posting here. I ll withdraw or delete the post if it is out of place.

Comment: @ChronicUser It is about KVM hosted on Linux, although the client is Windows, that seems on topic to me. I just want to make sure you understand want questions and answers that potentially help people other people as well. Apart from that we don't want chit-chat (which is why I edited out your thanks)

Answer (score 4):

Solution:
Activate the Windows 10 guest with a licence key for windows 10 pro and then the VM will be able to utilize all the CPU core that you assigned to it from the Linux host.

Answer (score 3):

For the record, I was able to get around this annoying windows 10 Home version limitation on Ubuntu 18.04 (beta) by the following:

1. In KVM Virt-Manager click on the “CPUs” tool,
2. Check the “Manually set CPU topology” box,
3. Assign 1 socket (this is what is limited by windows home),
4. I've got an 8700K CPU so selected 3 cores and 2 threads. “Current allocation” auto enter is then “6” (of 12 available).
5. windows reports 6 virtual cores
6. Checked htop in the host while playing netflix in windows and could
   see all of the cores taking a hit (and good performance) as opposed
   to before there was poor performance and only a limited core
   response.